# Polylang - How to add " add_filter" in a plugin or mu-plugin before the action ‘plugins_loaded’ has been fired

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, polylang

I'm trying to change the flag to a custom flag in svg, and I found this "pll_custom_flag" function in their document(https://polylang.pro/doc/filter-reference/)

There, it says "The filter needs to be added in a plugin or mu-plugin before the action ‘plugins_loaded’ has been fired. It can’t work in the functions.php of a theme."

However, I don't know where and how to add this action specifically.

Here is the action I I customized for my website.

```
add_filter( ‘pll_custom_flag’, ‘pll_custom_flag’, 10, 2 );

function pll_custom_flag( $flag, $code ) {
$flag[‘url’] = "http://example.com/wp-content/polylang/flags-custom/{$code}.svg";
$flag[‘height’] = 24;
return $flag;
}
```

I also added two svg images to a new directory(flags-custom) I created under the polylang directory.

I have almost zero knowledge in PHP, and I would greatly appreciate it if anyone could help me on this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1:
You need to create plugin for this filter. Create one and put this filter into it.

Solution 2 (simpler):
Put file (example: polylang_filters.php) into /wp-content/mu-plugins with this filter.

After 1 or 2 go to Polylang Settings -> Url modification and click save. No changes required just click save to update urls.

If you have your custom flags in folder they will show up.

PS.

I would prefer to keep my flags in theme folder:

```
add_filter( 'pll_custom_flag', 'pll_custom_flag', 10, 2 );

function pll_custom_flag( $flag, $code ) {
    $flag['url']    = get_template_directory_uri()."/img/lang_flags/{$code}.svg";
    $flag['width']  = 20;
    $flag['height'] = 20;
    return $flag;
}
```

In my flag folder I have flags:
gb.svg
de.svg
etc...

Answer (score 0):

additionally to the post mentioned above, you can use the following code, if you use a child-theme:

add_filter( 'pll_custom_flag', 'pll_custom_flag', 10, 2 );

```
function pll_custom_flag( $flag, $code ) {
    $flag['url']    = get_stylesheet_directory_uri()."/polylang/{$code}.svg";
    $flag['width']  = 28;
    $flag['height'] = 28;
    return $flag;
}
```

I have the flags in the child-theme/polylang/ folder.
After -> Polylang Settings -> Url modification and click save you will see in case the flag file name are wrong, the correct ones in the inspector of your browser by inspecting the language name on your page.

I hope that helps. :-)